# Is there an access command better than <>

Tags: ms-access

In access i Have a query where I want to exclude certain account numbers (very few like 10 out of 80K) Is there a better command than <> account number AND <> account number 2 AND <> account number 3

thanks
David

Answer (score 2):

You can use NOT IN, e.g.,

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE [account number] NOT IN (2, 3, 5, 11)
```

instead of

```sql
SELECT ... 
WHERE [account number] <> 2
    AND [account number] <> 3
    AND [account number] <> 5
    AND [account number] <> 11
```